# Close - Suggested SE site redirecton entries - can we add Network Engineering SE as an option?

Tags: feature-request, close

I was wondering if ServerFault could add Network Engineering to one of the allowable sites for close redirection.

Comment: To those of you that downvoted remember this is a forum for suggesting ideas, discussion, and making comments on them.  Simply downvoting suggestions is not really that valuable in a meta forum.  What we all want to encourage is suggestions even though others might not agree.

Comment: Downvotes on meta [indicate disagreement](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: I thought that they indicate problems with the formation, formatting, or research on a specific question.

Comment: From the linked document under the heading **Voting is different on meta.** _Votes on meta are generally used to express agreement or disagreement with a particular idea, rather than indicating the quality of research or factual correctness of a post... _

Comment: thanks for the correcting my misperception.

Answer (score 12):

I'm against this primarily on the grounds that NE is 100% overlapping with SF. So there's absolutely no reason anyone should be migrating a Question there unless the OP requests that it be migrated.

Comment: Rather, NE should just migrate everything here...

Comment: Meh, if they can be successful as a duplicate, more power to them I guess...

Answer (score 7):

This question seems to be largely a duplicate of:

[Will/Should Serverfault be dropping the "networking support" in the upcoming future?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5449/will-should-serverfault-be-dropping-the-networking-support-in-the-upcoming-fut)

The takeaway from that earlier discussion is that the way NE is currently defined, it overlaps 100% with SF - any question that's on-topic there is also on-topic here.  So it doesn't make sense to have an off-topic migration path from here to there.

Comment: yep, I learned there that the NE site experts might handle higher end exceptions from SF, but once you are at the level to be on-topic for them then you are probably already proficient enough to figure it out or your next step is usually the OEM TAC and not a forum.

Answer (score 5):

This can't happen until NE 'graduates'. Built in migration paths to [Beta sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52519/network-engineering) is something SE doesn't allow as a rule.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I'm not sure what the point of NE is; network engineering is really a component of systems administration, and in smaller scenarios is even usually done by sysadmins.  The skill set is the same and most people I know in my field have at least a CCNA if not a CCNP.

Migrating questions unnecessarily simply annoys users and redirects efforts from closing things that are garbage, deduplicating, and migrating things that are actually off topic here.  I can't think of any scenario under which a migration to NE would be appropriate, though the converse is not true.