# "bumped to the homepage by Community" generate mostly noise

Tags: discussion, low-quality

Just as sample: [such type of questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/351009/tortoise-svn-checkout-via-lan) must be closed as offtopic (due to [low-level quality](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6701/server-fault-needs-professional-quality-questions-not-just-questions-from-profe)) on 2012, and anyway **not forced** to homepage from trashcan and oblivion in 2017!

I saw such (noisy) bumping some times before, just can't resist now. Please stop degradation of SE!!!

Comment: In short: the community as a whole doesn't vote enough : http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6418/37681

Comment: @HBruijn - not related. Community may be silent, lazy, haters of "gamification"... any really. But in *professional environment* lazy lame questions **must NOT be forced** regardless of votes they have or miss

Comment: If bumping now produce bad results, it's time to fix it, not to explain why shit happens. IMNSHO

Comment: Make like everyone else, and click **question** and then click **newest**, (but it produce the result as @HBruijn 's told, those question don't get vote (good or bad))

Comment: It *is* related. Things get bumped because they don't have votes.

Comment: @yagmoth555 - I'm interested **in changed** information also, and prefer do not act as 1001 lemming. It's my style, don't dictate me to change it

Comment: @TRiG - OK. "Idiots are idiots because they are idiots". **Do not kick a dead horse** will be more fair play

Comment: @LazyBadger I dont dictate, but for change like you propose you will need to propose on meta stackexchange .. and good luck there, my tone was with that in mind, not against you

Answer (score 3):

Remember that voting in all of it's forms is community oversight. It's not about giving away a PhD, you don't need to solve the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) information just needs to be clear and correct/helpful.

Voting on Q&A is intended to solve the following problem

> How do you know that the information in a post is useful?

Without voting, Q&A on SE is largely no better than finding information on a random blog on the internet.

Among other things the [Community User](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community) rummages around in the sewer and pulls out Q&A that have answers but no votes and chucks them at the front page in the hope that someone will look at them and vote as appropriate. It even has this to say on the post notice

> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

The easiest way to stop stuff from being bumped by the community user is to simply vote.

Comment: I don't want to vote on middle-quality bullshit "just for peace". Community User makes monkey-job now, and in shit-style!

Comment: Looking at your profile you vote on almost nothing - shrugs. Downvotes work too.